# Apache POI: Overlapping Data Labels on Doughnut Chart

Tags: java, excel, charts, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to create doughnut charts in an Excel sheet, but I'm running into an issue where the data labels overlap, as shown in the attached screenshots. The problem seems to occur when the chart contains small percentage values that are positioned too close to each other.

```
    private static void createDoughnutChart(final XSSFSheet sheet, final String[] categories, final Number[] values,
                                            final List<byte[]> farbecode, final String titleText, final int col1,
                                            final int row1, final int col2, final int row2, final boolean firstChart) {
        // Create a drawing patriarch to allow the addition of charts and shapes to the sheet.
        final XSSFDrawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

        // Create an anchor point for the chart within the worksheet.
        final XSSFClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, col1, row1, col2, row2);
        // Set the anchor type to prevent the chart from moving or resizing with cells.
        anchor.setAnchorType(ClientAnchor.AnchorType.DONT_MOVE_AND_RESIZE);

        // Create a chart at the specified anchor point.
        final XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
        // Set the chart's title and prevent overlaying it over the chart.
        chart.setTitleText(titleText);
        chart.setTitleOverlay(false);

        // Access and modify the chart title's text properties.
        final CTTitle title = chart.getCTChart().getTitle();
        final CTTextBody textBody = title.getTx().getRich();
        final CTTextParagraph[] paragraphs = textBody.getPArray();
        // Set the font size of the title's first paragraph to 12pt.
        final CTTextCharacterProperties textProps = paragraphs[0].getRArray(0).getRPr();
        textProps.setSz(1200); // The size is in hundredths of a point, so 1200 = 12pt.

        // Add or access the chart's legend, set its position, and prevent overlay.
        final XDDFChartLegend legend = chart.getOrAddLegend();
        legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.BOTTOM);
        legend.setOverlay(false); // This prevents the legend from overlaying the chart, making it render outside the plot area.

        // Sort the chart values before plotting, if necessary.
        sortValues(categories, values);

        // Configure the legend's text properties (though it seems to be incomplete or unnecessary as per this snippet).
        final XDDFTextBody legendTextBody = new XDDFTextBody(legend);
        legendTextBody.getXmlObject().addNewBodyPr();
        legend.setTextBody(legendTextBody);

        // Create data sources from arrays for categories and values.
        final XDDFDataSource<String> categorySource = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(categories);
        final XDDFNumericalDataSource<Number> valueSource = XDDFDataSourcesFactory.fromArray(values);

        // Create doughnut chart data, set properties like color variation and hole size.
        final XDDFDoughnutChartData data = (XDDFDoughnutChartData) chart.createData(ChartTypes.DOUGHNUT, null, null);
        data.setVaryColors(true); // Allows different colors for each category.
        data.setHoleSize(50); // Sets the size of the doughnut chart's hole as a percentage of the plot area.

        // Add series to the chart data and enable leader lines.
        final XDDFChartData.Series series = data.addSeries(categorySource, valueSource);
        series.setShowLeaderLines(true);

        // Ensure manual layout for the legend is set and configure its position and size.
        if (!chart.getCTChart().getLegend().isSetLayout()) {
            chart.getCTChart().getLegend().addNewLayout();
        }
        if (chart.getCTChart().getLegend().getLayout().isSetManualLayout()) {
            chart.getCTChart().getLegend().getLayout().unsetManualLayout();
        }

        chart.getCTChart().getLegend().getLayout().addNewManualLayout();
        chart.getCTChart().getLegend().getLayout().getManualLayout().addNewXMode().setVal(
                org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STLayoutMode.EDGE);
        chart.getCTChart().getLegend().getLayout().getManualLayout().addNewYMode().setVal(
                org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.STLayoutMode.EDGE);
        chart.getCTChart().getLegend().getLayout().getManualLayout().addNewX().setVal(0.00); //0.00 from left //0.0
        chart.getCTChart().getLegend().getLayout().getManualLayout().addNewY().setVal(0.75); //0.70 from top
        chart.getCTChart().getLegend().getLayout().getManualLayout().addNewW().setVal(1.00); //1.00 width
        chart.getCTChart().getLegend().getLayout().getManualLayout().addNewH().setVal(0.24); //0.24 height

        // Reset and configure the legend's text properties.
        if (chart.getCTChart().getLegend().isSetTxPr()) {
            chart.getCTChart().getLegend().unsetTxPr();
        }
        chart.getCTChart().getLegend().addNewTxPr();
        chart.getCTChart().getLegend().getTxPr().addNewBodyPr();
        chart.getCTChart().getLegend().getTxPr().addNewP();
        chart.getCTChart().getLegend().getTxPr().getPArray(0).addNewPPr();
        chart.getCTChart().getLegend().getTxPr().getPArray(0).getPPr().addNewDefRPr().setSz(800); // Set font size for legend text.

        // Ensure the chart title is not automatically deleted.
        if (chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted() == null) {
            chart.getCTChart().addNewAutoTitleDeleted();
        }
        chart.getCTChart().getAutoTitleDeleted().setVal(false);


        // Get the total number of data points in the series.
        final int totalPoints = series.getCategoryData().getPointCount();

        // Initialize variables to calculate the sum and cumulative values of data points.
        double totalValue = 0.0;
        double cumulativeValue = 0.0;

        // Accumulate the total value of all data points.
        for (int i = 0; i < totalPoints; i++) {
            totalValue += (double) valueSource.getPointAt(i);
        }

        // Define the radius to shift data labels outside in percent of plot area.
        final double labelShiftRadius = 0.13;

        // Convert full circle degrees to radians for calculation.
        final double circleRadians = Math.toRadians(360);

        // Access the chart's data labels for modification.
        final CTDLbls dataLabels = chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0)
                .getSerArray(0).getDLbls();

        // Initialize a variable to adjust the radius for small value labels.
        float adjustmentRadius = 0;

        // Iterate through each data point to configure its label and position.
        for (int i = 0; i < totalPoints; i++) {
            // Calculate the value of the current data point as a percentage.
            final double valuePercent = ((double) valueSource.getPointAt(i) * 100);

            // Set the index for the current data point in the series.
            chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDPt()
                    .addNewIdx().setVal(i);

            // Set the color of the current data point.
            chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).getDPtArray(i)
                    .addNewSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(farbecode.get(i));

            // Configure the display of the data label for the current data point.
            dataLabels.addNewDLbl();
            dataLabels.getDLblArray(i).addNewIdx().setVal(i);
            dataLabels.getDLblArray(i).addNewShowVal().setVal(true); // Show the value percentage outside the circle.
            dataLabels.getDLblArray(i).addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
            dataLabels.getDLblArray(i).addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
            dataLabels.getDLblArray(i).addNewShowPercent().setVal(false); // Display full values.
            dataLabels.getDLblArray(i).addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);

            // Update the cumulative value for positioning calculations.
            cumulativeValue += (double) valueSource.getPointAt(i) / 2d;
            cumulativeValue += (double) valueSource.getPointAt(i) / 2d;

            // Check if the value percentage is less than or equal to 1.5% to adjust label position.
            if (valuePercent <= 1.5d) {
                cumulativeValue += (double) valueSource.getPointAt(i) / 2d;
                final double angle = circleRadians * (cumulativeValue / totalValue);
                cumulativeValue += (double) valueSource.getPointAt(i) / 2d;

                // Calculate the adjusted position for the data label.
                final double deltaX = Math.sin(angle) * (labelShiftRadius + adjustmentRadius);
                adjustmentRadius += 1.5F;
                final double deltaY = Math.cos(angle) * labelShiftRadius * -1;

                // Set the manual layout position for the data label.
                dataLabels.getDLblArray(i).addNewLayout().addNewManualLayout();
                dataLabels.getDLblArray(i).getLayout().getManualLayout().addNewX().setVal(deltaX);
                dataLabels.getDLblArray(i).getLayout().getManualLayout().addNewY().setVal(deltaY);
            }

            // Format data labels for values less than 1% and greater than 0% to "<1%".
            if (valuePercent < 1.0d && valuePercent > 0.0d) {
                dataLabels.getDLblArray(i).addNewNumFmt();
                dataLabels.getDLblArray(i).getNumFmt().setSourceLinked(false);
                dataLabels.getDLblArray(i).getNumFmt().setFormatCode("\"<1%\"");
            }
        }

        // Ensure data labels are set for the series. If not, add them.
        if (!chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).isSetDLbls()) {
            chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getDoughnutChartArray(0).getSerArray(0).addNewDLbls();
        }

        // Configure global data label settings: show values, hide series name, category name, percentage, and legend key.
        dataLabels.addNewShowVal().setVal(true); // Show data label values.
        dataLabels.addNewShowSerName().setVal(false); // Hide series name in data labels.
        dataLabels.addNewShowCatName().setVal(false); // Hide category name in data labels.
        dataLabels.addNewShowPercent().setVal(false); // Hide percentage in data labels.
        dataLabels.addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false); // Hide legend key in data labels.

        // Set the number format for data labels to a percentage format.
        dataLabels.addNewNumFmt();
        dataLabels.getNumFmt().setSourceLinked(false); // Use custom format instead of linked.
        dataLabels.getNumFmt().setFormatCode("#,##0%"); // Set format code for percentage.

        // Disable rounded corners for the chart space.
        if (chart.getCTChartSpace().getRoundedCorners() == null) chart.getCTChartSpace().addNewRoundedCorners();
        chart.getCTChartSpace().getRoundedCorners().setVal(false);

        // Configure text properties for data labels, including font size.
        dataLabels.addNewTxPr(); // Add new text properties.
        dataLabels.getTxPr().addNewBodyPr(); // Add body properties.
        dataLabels.getTxPr().addNewP(); // Add a new paragraph.
        dataLabels.getTxPr().getPArray(0).addNewPPr(); // Add paragraph properties.
        dataLabels.getTxPr().getPArray(0).getPPr().addNewDefRPr().setSz(750); // Set default run properties size (font size).

        // Set the chart space's outline to no fill, making it transparent.
        chart.getCTChartSpace().addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewNoFill();

        // Ensure a solid fill is set for the chart space, setting it to a specific color if not already done.
        if (chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr() == null) chart.getCTChartSpace().addNewSpPr();
        if (chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().isSetSolidFill()) chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().unsetSolidFill();
        final byte[] chartSpaceColor = new byte[]{(byte) 242, (byte) 242, (byte) 242}; // Light gray color.
        chart.getCTChartSpace().getSpPr().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(chartSpaceColor); // Light gray color.

        // Ensure the plot area layout is set. If not, add a manual layout.
        if (!chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().isSetLayout()) {
            chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().addNewLayout();
        }
        if (chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLayout().isSetManualLayout()) {
            chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLayout().unsetManualLayout(); // Remove existing manual layout if set.
        }
        // Add a new manual layout with specific settings for target, mode, and dimensions.
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLayout().addNewManualLayout();
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLayout().getManualLayout().addNewLayoutTarget().setVal(STLayoutTarget.INNER);
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLayout().getManualLayout().addNewXMode().setVal(STLayoutMode.EDGE);
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLayout().getManualLayout().addNewYMode().setVal(STLayoutMode.EDGE);
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLayout().getManualLayout().addNewX().setVal(0.10); // Position 10% from the left edge.
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLayout().getManualLayout().addNewY().setVal(0.15); // Position 11% from the top edge.
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLayout().getManualLayout().addNewW().setVal(0.80); // Width is 80% of total.
        chart.getCTChart().getPlotArea().getLayout().getManualLayout().addNewH().setVal(0.60); // Height is 60% of total.

        if (firstChart) {
            final List<Integer> indexList = getRemovableIndexList(categories);
            for (final Integer integer : indexList) {
                final XDDFLegendEntry legendEntry = getOrAddLegendEntry(legend, integer);
                legendEntry.setDelete(true);
            }
        }
        chart.plot(data);
    }
```

I've tried adjusting the label positions by manipulating the deltaX and deltaY values based on the angle calculation in the for loop where the labels are set. However, this doesn't seem to resolve the overlapping issue when the chart contains many small segments.

The overlap does not happen every time, which makes it challenging to debug. When the chart has many small segments, the problem becomes more apparent, but it's not consistent across all such charts.

Screenshots for reference:
[image: here: they are not overlapping]

[image: they are overlapping]

How can I programmatically adjust the data labels to prevent them from overlapping when dealing with multiple small segments in a doughnut chart using Apache POI?

Comment: My complete example in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77515681/how-to-setup-apache-poi-doughnut-chart-label-outside-of-chart-using-leaderline/77534966#77534966 works for me with any kind of small segments. Tries using `... else cell.setCellValue(Math.round(Math.random() * 100d * 10d) / 10d); ...` while creating the data. Played around using different `NUM_OF_COLUMNS`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. it did not resolve my problem.